# Write unicode 0x2 in Java

Tags: java, unicode, character-encoding

How can I write the unicode character `0x{2}` in Java?

I try with `"\u0002"` but is doesn't seem to work.

The reason I need to find this character is because I need to replace it in a XML file, before I can be able to parse it.

The error I get while parsing mentions: `An invalid XML character (Unicode: 0x{2}) was found in the value of attribute "{1}" and element is "4".` and replacing `\u0002` doesn't resolve the error.

This is how I am parsing:

```
try {
    // Fixing any invalid characters in the XML file
    fixXMLFile(xmlFile);

    // Get a factory
    SAXParserFactory spf = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();

    // Get a new instance of parser
    SAXParser sp = spf.newSAXParser();

    // Parse the file and also register this class for call backs
    sp.parse(xmlFile, this);

} catch(Exception e) {
    System.out.println(e.getLocalizedMessage());
}
```

And the fix method:

```
private void fixXMLFile(File xmlFile) throws IOException {
    File tempFile = File.createTempFile("dont_delete", ".tmp");
    FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(tempFile);

    Reader fr = new FileReader(xmlFile);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);

    int sdds = 0;
    while(br.ready()) {
        String tmp = br.readLine();
        if (tmp.contains("\u0002")) System.out.println(++sdds);
        fw.write(tmp.replaceAll("\u0002", "") + "\n");
    }

    fw.close();
    br.close();
    fr.close();

    // Finally replace the original file.
    tempFile.renameTo(xmlFile);
}
```

Comment: What didn't work when you used `\u0002`?

Comment: Simple: `if (myString.contains("\u0002")) System.out.println("Found it");` this doesn't find it.

Comment: Can you people please stop voting down and read the actual question?

Comment: so how so you know its there? searched with another tool like text pad? are you confusing the character with the escape value?

Comment: The error I get while parsing the XML document is: `An invalid XML character (Unicode: 0x{2}) was found in the value of attribute "{1}" and element is "4".` and replacing `\u0002` doesn't resolve the error.

Comment: Can you post some source code, and/or the file you're trying to parse?

Comment: I added my code. The file is huge I cannot post it here.

Answer (score 0):

I found it. `0x{2}` in the error message is `"\u0004"` in Java. Replacing that eliminates the error message.

Comment: My guess is that your SAX library has a bug, and that `{2}` should have been expended to 0004 and `{1}` to whatever is the attribute that contained \u0004.

Comment: I agree with Etienne.  It appears the parser author intended to use that error message as a `MessageFormat` format string, but forgot to do so.  `{1}` and `{2}` are placeholders for format arguments.

Answer (score -1):

That character is not allowed is XML, see Wikipediate for ref: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valid_characters_in_XML#XML_1.0

Comment: I know it's not allowed. This is why I am asking how I can replace it in my question above.